# Behringer UMC202HD white noise

Tags: noise, audio-interfaces, guitar, behringer

I just got a Behringer UMC202HD. Thing is there is white noise which is audible when I am plugging my guitar and having high gain on.

I am wondering if that's normal for every interface, or should I go for a Focusrite Scarlett Solo or 2i2 instead? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you provide some more information… You say you plug your guitar; how do you do that? Is the input High-Z? What is the pre-amplification?

Comment: Are you using some kind of amp sim, or is this just 'straight in the desk'? Cos, fer sure, guitars through high-gain amps [or sims] are noisy beasts.